# ORM in Android can copy and merge context?

Tags: android, orm

Wondering exist any ORM in Android I can **copy** and **merge** 'context', memory content? In iOS with `Core Data` I can make a full copy of memory map, do work with it, and changes can merge back to the original `memory map` is it possible in Android?

I have heard about, but none of them seems to support it by default.

OrmLite : http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml

GreenDao : http://greendao-orm.com/

Comment: I think you are confusing this with android [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) here, might be wrong though!

Comment: For complex requirements you can go through Content provider in Android